# Calculate grand total

Tags: sql-server

I have a query to calculate the total amount after the addition of taxes and price for quantity. I have created a formula that calculates the values fine if all the fields are filled.
My problem is that if a single field is not entered which in some cases is not applicable than the result I get is NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE StockRequest
(
ID Int,
Item Varchar(25),
RequestedQty Int,
Price Int,
MiscExpense Int,
ExchangeRate Int
);

INSERT INTO StockRequest VALUES (1, 'Bottle', '2', '25', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO StockRequest VALUES (2, 'Mouse', '10', '150', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO StockRequest VALUES (3, 'Mouse Pad', '5', '70', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO StockRequest VALUES (4, 'Glass', '6', '100', '2', NULL);
INSERT INTO StockRequest VALUES (5, 'Cup', '6', '50', NULL, '3');


SELECT Item, RequestedQty, Price, (RequestedQty*Price)+MiscExpense+ExchangeRate AS [Total]
FROM StockRequest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go with ISNULL**

```
SELECT Item, RequestedQty, Price, 
    (RequestedQty*Price)+ISNULL(MiscExpense,0)+ISNULL(ExchangeRate,0) AS [Total]
FROM StockRequest
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Item                      RequestedQty Price       Total
------------------------- ------------ ----------- -----------
Bottle                    2            25          55
Mouse                     10           150         1500
Mouse Pad                 5            70          355
Glass                     6            100         602
Cup                       6            50          303

(5 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should check columns before doing the math if it is `null` or not using `ISNULL`

```
SELECT Item, RequestedQty, Price,
(ISNULL(RequestedQty, 1)*ISNULL(Price, 1))+ISNULL(MiscExpense, 
1)+ISNULL(ExchangeRate, 1)AS [Total]
FROM StockRequest
```

`ISNULL` checks column value that if it is null or not. if null then it sets the column value to given parameter (i gave `1` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) function.

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

Not tested, but probably alright:

```
SELECT 
    [Item]
  , [RequestedQty]
  , [Price]
  , (ISNULL([RequestedQty], 0) * ISNULL([Price], 0) + ISNULL([MiscExpense], 0) + ISNULL([ExchangeRate], 0)) AS [Total]
FROM [StockRequest];
```

UPDATE: Of course, the replacement value has to be chosen based on the desired business logic.